# OpenBSD NIC Cards Not Configured (Kernel Edit)

Tags: kernel, nic, openbsd

I have recently installed OpenBSD v6.8 on a SuperMicro server. During the initial installation I couldn't setup the NIC cards because I didn't have any IP Information. I assume this setup skip caused the kernel to exclude these cards and now when I run ICONFIG, the NIC cards do not show up. Looking in DMESG I see the following:

```
"Intel X722 10GBASE-T" rev 0x09 at pci7 dev 0 function 0 not configured

"Intel X722 10GBASE-T" rev 0x09 at pci7 dev 0 function 1 not configured
```

So my question is, what do I need to modify so that when I reboot the server, I can run ICONFIG and see these NICs show up so they can be configured with IP Info?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. It turns out that I installed i386/OpenBSD which say these NIC Cards as "not configured". But I went back and installed AMD/OpenBSD and the OS was able to see these cards so I could configure them.

Lesson learned. When in doubt, check which OS architecture you are installing.

Answer (score 0):

Not supported by OpenBSD, see https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/sys/dev/pci/pcidevs#L5067

Show `pcidump -v` for your device.

Maybe your device is just a revision of older device and it could work, see https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/c85bea54589d280252139cfe3e00d8f5569f1265/sys/dev/pci/if_ixl.c#L1627.

Comment: Thanks. That is going to suck. I might have to switch this from being Native OpenBSD to running as a VM on VMWare which can utilize the NIC card.

Comment: *pcidevs* file does not mean it is not supported, it is just "known" by named, IIUC. You should provide `pcidump -v` output first.